# Toggling EF Core logs for reads and writes separately

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

To toggle EF Core SQL logging, one can use this in `appsettings.json`:

```json
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    //...
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information" //or "Warning"
  }
}
```

In development, EF Core logs queries by default at the "Information" level; so one can silence those with "Warning".

*But that applies to both reads and writes*. When I have EF problems, it's almost always with writes - so I enable logging, and get a flood of read logs which make debugging difficult.

Is it possible to toggle logging for reads and writes separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to toggle logging for reads and writes separately?

**Use this in only Development Environment**

I would go about it this way:

Using the [DbCommandInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.dbcommandinterceptor?view=efcore-7.0) class to intercept the sql statements executed.
So firstly I create a class `QueryCommandInterceptor`  inheriting `DbCommandInterceptor`:

```cs
public class QueryCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
 private readonly ILogger<QueryCommandInterceptor> _logger;

 public QueryCommandInterceptor(ILogger<QueryCommandInterceptor> logger)
 {
     _logger = logger;
 }
}
```

Add the method to check if the command is a write operation i.e `DELETE`,`UPDATE`,`INSERT` and also to log the command if it is:

```cs
private void LogCommand(DbCommand command)
{
    if (command.CommandText.Contains("INSERT") ||
           command.CommandText.Contains("UPDATE") ||
           command.CommandText.Contains("DELETE"))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Executing SQL command: {command.CommandText}");
    }
}
```

The final `QueryCommandInterceptor` overriding methods in the `DbCommandInterceptor` :

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class QueryCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        private readonly ILogger<QueryCommandInterceptor> _logger;

        public QueryCommandInterceptor(ILogger<QueryCommandInterceptor> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public override InterceptionResult<int> NonQueryExecuting(
           DbCommand command,
           CommandEventData eventData,
           InterceptionResult<int> result)
        {
            LogCommand(command);
            return result;
        }

        public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> NonQueryExecutingAsync(
            DbCommand command,
            CommandEventData eventData,
            InterceptionResult<int> result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            LogCommand(command);
            return new ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>>(result);
        }

        public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
            DbCommand command,
            CommandEventData eventData,
            InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
        {
            LogCommand(command);
            return result;
        }

        public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
            DbCommand command,
            CommandEventData eventData,
            InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            LogCommand(command);
            return new ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>>(result);
        }

        public override InterceptionResult<object> ScalarExecuting(
           DbCommand command,
           CommandEventData eventData,
           InterceptionResult<object> result)
        {
            LogCommand(command);
            return result;
        }

        public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<object>> ScalarExecutingAsync(
            DbCommand command,
            CommandEventData eventData,
            InterceptionResult<object> result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            LogCommand(command);
            return new ValueTask<InterceptionResult<object>>(result);
        }
        private void LogCommand(DbCommand command)
        {
            if (command.CommandText.Contains("INSERT") ||
                   command.CommandText.Contains("UPDATE") ||
                   command.CommandText.Contains("DELETE"))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Executing SQL command: {command.CommandText}");
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Finally wire up my logger in my `Program.cs`, also adding the new Interceptor:

```cs
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConsole();
}).CreateLogger<QueryCommandInterceptor>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<StackContext>(options => 
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    options.AddInterceptors(new QueryCommandInterceptor(logger)); 
}
);
```